# Changing standard button bitmap of tool/command in ArcGIS Engine

Tags: arcgis-engine

I'd like to use some of the standard 'out of the box' esri tools e.g. Measure Tool in an ArcGIS Engine 10 app, but I'd like to change the default bitmap of the tool button.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think *inheriting* the measuretool and overriding ICommand.Bitmap will work, but haven't tried it lately.

So instead, you might try creating a new tool (MyMeasureTool), and use *containment*, with a contained member variable for the tool whose bitmap you want to change.  Instantiate the contained command/tool in ICommand.OnCreate.  Forward all ICommand and ITool methods to the contained command, except for ICommand.Bitmap for which you'll return a handle to your preferred bitmap.